# Crash when using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

My app keeps crashing everytime i call this method

> setImageWithURL

I've installed SDWebImage using pods and included -ObjC in other linker flags.

Here's the console log :

> -[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd06a930
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd06a930'

Comment: And the compiler gives no warnings on the line with `[UIImageView setImageWithURL:]`?

Comment: crash report tells no method named `steImageWithURL` in `UIImageVew`.

Comment: I've imported UIImageView+WebCache.h to my .m file.

Comment: Well it looks like you are including the category header file but the category implementation file isn't linked into your app.